# Run code synchronously after element removed from DOM

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to synchronously run code AFTER a component's element is removed from the DOM?

In other words I'd like to do this:

```
componentDidUnmount: function(){
  var thisEl = this.getDOMNode();
  var docEl = document.documentElement;
  assert(!docEl.contains(thisEl));
}
```

...instead of something hacky like this:

```
componentWillUnmount: function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var thisEl = this.getDOMNode();
    var docEl = document.documentElement;
    assert(!docEl.contains(thisEl));
  }.bind(this), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this in the parent.  After componentWillUnmount, your component is considered at the end of its life, and can no longer do anything.

The parent's componentDidUpdate will be called after a child's componentWillUnmount.  A complicated example of this can be found in [ReactTransitionGroup.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/transitions/ReactTransitionGroup.js#L91), which is the only use case for this I can think of.

Comment: "The parent's componentDidUpdate will be called after a child's componentWillUnmount" -- I can't get this to work. But maybe it's only true if the parent element isn't also being unmounted?